# Grub menu still shows after Ubuntu uninstallation

Tags: grub2

I'm not sure this is technically the grub menu as I don't really have much knowledge with Ubuntu. 
But, when I boot my computer I'm given the option to boot into Windows 8.1 or Ubuntu. I've tried:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

but I still receive the option to boot Ubuntu. I also went to `msconfig` to delete Ubuntu from the boot tab but it wasn't there so I don't really know how to proceed. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove GRUB on make default bootloader as window using **Easy BCD** on Windows. You can customize all bootloaders with **Easy BCD**

Answer (score 0):

here is a good article (german) about it: [→](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/grub#GRUB-deinstallieren).

Summarizing it in English:

Use our installation CD of Windows Vista/7/8 to delete GRUB. After selecting your language, choose repair computer. start the command prompt after the program searched existing windows installations. Type:

```
Bootrec /FixMbr.
Bootrec /FixBoot
exit
```

GRUB will be deleted and windows will boot.